# zxing And Aforge aztec Barcode Reading

Tags: zxing, aforge, aztec-barcode

```
private readonly IBarcodeReader barcodeReader;
barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader {
    AutoRotate = true,
    Options = new DecodingOptions {
        TryHarder = true,
        PossibleFormats = new List < BarcodeFormat {
            BarcodeFormat.AZTEC
        }
    }
};
currentBitmapForDecoding = new Bitmap(@ "F:\Aztec-Code-Scandit.png");
Result result = barcodeReader.Decode(currentBitmapForDecoding);
```

it working when i read image from physical path.but when i assign current frame
of webcam to `currentBitmapForDecoding` it unabel to reade Aztec `Barcode.pls` anyone how help me to read aztec barcode from web cam.i also make frame size small but not work.